# Android webview onReceivedError() not called when webpage responds with error status

Tags: android, webview

onReceivedError() is called if the webview tries to load some non-existent page, but it is not called if the server/website chooses to respond with an error status, such as status 500.

```
# Django returning status 500
return HttpResponseServerError("returned status 500")
```

This response appears in the regular Chrome browser with status 500. However, the webview just loads it, never calling onReceivedError().

How can the app/webview tell if the server is sending back an error status? I need to handle it like any error.

Thanks!

Comment: [Related](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36905665).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here [Android Developer WebViewClient.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

You can read here on which errors onReivedError is responding. HTML error 500 (internal server error is not within it). Further on ReceivedError is deprecated since version 23. You can read this all in the former link.

I was looking around very quickly and found more questions about how to get the http errors, mostly the answers were negative.

So maybe you can use a trick by testing the website with an HttpURLConnection and use the method getResponseCode to get the status of your server. You can for example put a small file on the server and then you try to get this small file with HttpURLConnection. If there is an internal server error you will receive a 500 error as response. And then you can handle things like you want.

I know this is not the most elegant answer, but as I said maybe you can use some kind of trick.